# Map my root url to a subdirectory

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, alias

My question is rather simple: how do i alias my url root to one of my subdirectories?

Suppose my site's url is

```
https://example.com
```

and my document root is

```
/home/user/web
```

However, I want to above URL to access

```
/home/user/web/app
```

I can't seem to use

```
Alias / /app/
```

I try to follow this similar answers [here] ([.htaccess: Redirect root url to subdirectory, but retain root url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774421/htaccess-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory-but-retain-root-url]))
to add

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/app/.*$ https://example.com/
```

I will end up with:

```
This page isn’t working
example.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the httpd.conf? Then you could simply change the DocumentRoot

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/web/app"
```

Or if you got more domains on that machine use virtual hosts.
Or rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/app/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://example.com/apps
```

another option would be a symlink on the filesystem.

First try without https - to see plain http working.

Comment: Thanks, if I change the DocumentRoot, then I can't access e.g. example.com/app2 (Permission Denied)

Comment: No, you should find it under '/home/user/web/app/app2' - if this is not wanted use a different approach depending on all your constraints. If this answer was helpful please vote it up or/and mark as answer. If more is needed to be satisfied you have to provide more info - from your information I don't see a reason why this answer should not be enough.